# Saving an upload image's extension

Tags: php, security, upload

Is it necessary to abandon an uploaded image's extension when saving it above document root? I'm thinking of calling the image through `img.php?i=thisImage.png`, where inside the name of the image is run through `mb_split('.',$_GET['i'])` and the latter is used as inside `header('Content-Type: image/$img[1]')`. As my personal opinion, it doesn't seem to matter either way, be it `img.php?i=thisImage.png` or `img.php?i=thisImage`, but I'm always about tightening security.

Also, what are some of the best methods, aside from a PHP proxy with `Content-Type:` `Content-Length:` and serving the images from above document root? I've heard mixed opinions about copying the image from source through IM, but as I've said they're mixed opinions.

Comment: Note: The content type is not always the same as the extension. You can save a bitmap as .png, or a jpeg as .gif! You also save a jpeg as .jpg, while its content-type header should be `image/jpeg`, not `image/jpg`.

Comment: Do you know of any offhand solutions for checking the real image type?

Comment: Also be very wary of putting user input into HTTP headers - it's a vector for HTTP response splitting and XSS in older PHP versions.

Comment: Only images are allowed and there is already a check for `if not jpg png gif jpeg`, which I'm guessing is what you were pointing towards. If not I'm not sure what you're alluding to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of no problems with leaving the file-name alone, if the file is saved outside the web-accessible area and pushed to the client through a script.

The method I use (in KFM, and in my CMS), is to use mod_rewrite to redirect calls to a script which will retrieve the file for you.

For instance, if you have the URL /f/file.jpg, but the file is actually located at ../files/file.jpg, then you use mod_rewrite to "catch" the request and redirect it to a script. For instance:

```
RewriteRule ^f/(.*)$ /get-file.php?filename=$1 [L]
```

then write get-file.php, using something like readfile() to pass the file through

Comment: `mod_rewrite` seems like it would be a good solution for someone requiring redirection to their script. However if one takes security in mind ahead of time it's just as easy to point to the file you're delivering the image through and avoid the unnecessary step. ;)

Comment: true. my answer was based on my own preference, which is that I don't want the reader seeing some "unnatural" URL.

Comment: If the user is worried about the URL and not the content they're a bit 'above average'. There are quite a number of websites that don't use 'natural' URL. Such as SO. If I was worried about it, I'd expect to see `.php` or `.html`.